# SQL- how to sum values from table between value to value?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to sum rows in select from value to value.
for example:

```
table T:
value:        type:
1              5
2              10
2              8
3              10
3              2
```

I want to sum the values from the last type 10 (the last two "3" values)
do you have an idea how to do it?
thanks in advance!

Comment: What you actually want?

Comment: sorry, I didn't explain myself good maybe, I want to sum just the the last values. in my example just from the last '10' type till the end, the result should be 6- (3+3) the query should go over the table and from the last '10' type it should sum the values. thanks!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select value,sum(type) as SumofType
From T
Group by value
```

Comment: sorry, I didn't explain myself good maybe, I want to sum just the the last values. in my example just from the last '10' type till the end, the result should be 6-  (3+3) the query should go over the table and from the last '10' type it should sum the values. thanks!

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this SQL.

```
   Select value,sum(type) as Sum_Type
    From Ta where value=3
    Group by value
```